# jquery data selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use a jquery data selector to add/remove a class to an element.

```
$("#side_categories .testbox").click(function () {
    var category = $(this).data('category'); //get the category from the clicked button

    if ($('#side_categories .testbox').hasClass('activated')) {
        //otherInput is the hidden text input
        $('#listings .deals:data("category"="+category+")').removeClass('activated');
    } else {
        $('#listings .deals:data("category"="+category+")').addClass('activated');
    }
});
```

In my test box I have data-category set on each trigger to pass it over.  The category going into data-category is filled in via php.

Can't seem to get this to work,  have been seeing errors like:

```
regular expression too complex
[Break On This Error] while (m = matcher.exec(expr)) {
```

or when I'm using the older function written by james padolsey, i get the following:

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: data
```

I just want to be able to add/remove classes from LI's based on checkbox selections.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work instead?

```
$("#side_categories .testbox").click(function () {
    var category = $(this).data('category'); //get the category from the clicked button
    $('#listings .deals[data-category*="' + category + '"]').toggleClass('activated');
});
```

Comment: far as i understood, "data-category" was part of the .data api which should read the -category

Comment: yes, but as @zzzzBov said, because there's no `:data()` selector, the above solution would be an alternate :) something similar was suggested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value

Comment: YESSS!!! thank you!   huge thanks to everyone for their input!  so far this has been a few hours of unnecessary headaches! :)

Comment: I was following http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/a-better-data-selector-for-jquery/ as well as the updated functions/plugins but the above code did the trick! :)

Comment: btw, it's customary to mark the proposed solution that resolved your issue as the answer to your original question :)

Comment: what do u do in an event when both solutions work?  feels somewhat awkward lol

Comment: @Mike i usually select the one that i am going to actually use.

Answer (score 6):

Make it so you can filter by the `data` value:

```
$('#listings .deals').filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).data('category') == category;
}).removeClass('activated');
```

---

[`.filter()` in jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

---

**WORKING CODE**:

```
$("#side_categories .testbox").click(function () {
    var category = $(this).data('category'); //get the category from the clicked button
    var these_deals = $('#listings .deals').filter(function (index) {
            return $(this).data('category') == category;
        });
    $('#listings .deals').removeClass('activated');
    if (these_deals.hasClass('activated')) {
        //otherInput is the hidden text input
        these_deals.removeClass('activated');
    } else {
        these_deals.addClass('activated');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/CcfwX/

Comment: huge thanks for this!  95% sure its my own error, but i couldn't get this to work

Comment: @Mike -- what are the errors that you have on the page? Can you put you code into a http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: I wasn't getting any error, just nothing was happening. and firebug didn't report anythign at all

Comment: @Mike can I see your sample code? (with html, maybe it isnt selecting properly)

Comment: yes! thank you!  seems i dont have enough reputation here to vote on things.   but again, huge thanks to everyone!

Comment: @Mike -- please select an accepted answer. and you can **always** vote up! :-)

Comment: @Mike -- you are the question asker -- select an accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @Neal Thank you - I was having a bit of a struggle with some of my JS and your solution pointed me in a right direction and got my JS working based on yours.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't have a native `:data()` selector. You will need to explicitly define it on `$.expr[':'].data`, or use a plugin that adds it as a selector.

Comment: you can select it with `.filter()`, see my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try using single instead of double quotes around category, like this:

```
...
$('#listings .deals:data("category"='+category+')').removeClass('activated');
} else {
$('#listings .deals:data("category"='+category+')').addClass('activated');
...
```

If that doesn't work, try various combinations of adding and removing double quotes, like this, for instance:

```
...
$('#listings .deals:data(category="'+category+'")').removeClass('activated');
} else {
$('#listings .deals:data(category="'+category+'")').addClass('activated');
...
```

I'm not an expert at jQuery selectors, but you seem to be trying to use the variable category, rather than the string "+category+", in your selector, which your current code isn't doing, since the selector is surrounded by single quotes rather than double quotes.