# How to select elements with jQuery that have a certain value in a data attribute array

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

is there a way in jQuery to select elements that have a certain value in a data attribute array?

Consider this snippet of html:

```
<li id="person1" data-city="Boston, New York, San Fransisco">
    Person name 1
</li>
<li id="person1" data-city="Los Angeles, New York, Washington">
    Person name 2
</li>
```

What is the best way in jQuery to select all persons with "New York" in the data-city attribute?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value, which has a more thorough answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>even though i don't see your html,</strike> it should be:

```
$('[data-city*="New York"]')
```

Comment: i've corrected the html-snippet, you should be able to see it now. I think your solution only works if there was only one city in the data-city attribute

Comment: @murze: See it now, thanks. And no, `*=` is the attribute contains selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/