# How to select elements with jQuery that have a certain value in a data attribute array

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

is there a way in jQuery to select elements that have a certain value in a data attribute array?

Consider this snippet of html:

```
<li id="person1" data-city="Boston, New York, San Fransisco">
    Person name 1
</li>
<li id="person2" data-city="Los Angeles, New York, Washington">
    Person name 2
</li>
```

What is the best way in jQuery to select all persons with "New York" in the data-city attribute?

The solution should take in account that certain citynames appear in other city names (in example 2: London, New London)

Example 2:

```
<li id="person1" data-city="Boston, London, San Fransisco">
    Person name 1
</li>
<li id="person2" data-city="Los Angeles, Washington, New London">
    Person name 2
</li>
```

What is the best way in jQuery to select all persons with "London" in the data-city attribute? A city with "New London" should not be selected.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select elements with jQuery that have a certain value in a data attribute array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344353/how-to-select-elements-with-jquery-that-have-a-certain-value-in-a-data-attribute)

Comment: corrected the html so all elements have a unique id

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the selector `tag[attr*=string]` where `*=` matches the string found anywhere in the tag value. I have colored the text red, just so you can test...

```
$("li[data-city*=New York]").css({color:'red'});
```

Or via more complex method to fit needs of example two:

```
$("li")
    .filter( function(){ 
            return $(this).attr('data-city').match(/(^|,\s+)London(,|$)/) 
        })
    .css({color:'red'});
```

This method uses filter to go through the list of selected `li` and match all elements with attribute `data-city` that matches regex `(^|,\s+)London(,|$)` which means...

- start or comma (`^|,`)
- and one or more spaces (`\s+`)
- followed by `London`
- followed by comma or end (`,|$`)

I used this HTML:

```
<li id="person1" data-city="Boston, New York, San Fransisco, London">
    Person name 1
</li>
<li id="person2" data-city="Boston, New Jersey, London, San Fransisco">
    Person name 2
</li>
<li id="person3" data-city="Los Angeles, New York, New London, Washington">
    Person name 3
</li>
```

Comment: p.s. you should always use unique id field, if you want a type of thing rather than a specific thing, you should use class instead

Comment: thanks for solution but it doesn't solve the problem in example 2 (i've added another example to the question)

Comment: thank you @BillyMoon for the filter, it's what one of the [answer's comments here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4191718/1037948) alluded to

Comment: It's worth noting that every `li` on the page needs to have the attribute data-city or this will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

try something like :

```
$('li[data-city*="New York"]')
```

[`Attribute Contains Selector` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/#attributevalue)

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fR8rJ/)

Comment: thanks for solution but it doesn't solve the problem in example 2 (i've added another example to the question)