# How to find if a clicked item has a certain data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these two radio buttons

```
<input id="119715_0" type="radio" name="119715" value="76952" data-logic="yes" required /><label for="119715_0">Yes</label>

<input id="119715_1" type="radio" name="119715" value="76953" data-logic="no" required /><label for="119715_1">No</label>
```

I need to find out first, if they have the data-logic attribute and then the value in order to put together an if statement for if the value is yes or if the value is no. I cant use the id's because there might be multiple buttons on the page that have data-logic so I'm trying to use $(this) so it runs on whichever is getting clicked.

I've found this link [How to select elements with jQuery that have a certain value in a data attribute array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344361/how-to-select-elements-with-jquery-that-have-a-certain-value-in-a-data-attribute) but it's specific to just the type of tag. I dont know how to use it with $(this)

I have currently been messing around with

```
function checkLogic() { 

if ($(this).attr("data-logic")) {

alert("haslogic");

}
}

$("input").click(checkLogic);
```

but have been unsuccessful

Comment: Your code should work, have you out your code within document ready handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input").click(function() {
    var dataAttr = $(this).attr("data-logic");

    if (dataAttr == "yes") { 
      var value = $(this).attr("value");
      alert('Has logic ' + value);
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wCRLE/1/

Answer (score 3):

Check with the [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function:  http://jsfiddle.net/byzLG/1/

```
$('input[name="119715"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('logic') !== undefined) {
        alert('Has data-logic');
    } else {
        alert('Does not have data-logic');
    }
});​
```

Use case where `if ($(this).data('logic'))` didn't work as you wanted in my original code was if the value was 0.  I'm sure a value of false would have broken it as well.

Comment: Of course, this depends on `data-logic` containing a truthy value.

Answer (score 2):

use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
$("input").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).data("logic"))
    alert("haslogic");
});
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tDVxU/)**

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically
>   pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with
>   embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5
>   specification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain JavaScript:

```
if(element.getAttribute("data-logic") === null) {
   // Doesn't have attribute
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrmpj7nf/).

Answer (score 0):

You should check the values with types. Javascript is really wrong with types so you need to be extra cautious:

```
if (typeof($(this).attr('data-type')) === "undefined")
```