# How to get an element by its data-itemindex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Suppose I want to get `innerHTML` of below `<li>` by its data-itemindex. i even don't know it is possible or not.

```
<li id="li:90" class="liGrid" data-itemindex="3" data-itemid="li:90" >
winoria</li>
```

i tried

```
alert($("li").find("[data-itemindex=3]").html());
alert($("li[data-itemindex='3']").text());
```

from [How to select elements with jQuery that have a certain value in a data attribute array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344361/how-to-select-elements-with-jquery-that-have-a-certain-value-in-a-data-attribute/7344459#7344459) 
but doesnt help me.

Comment: `alert($("li[data-itemindex='3']").text());`

Comment: `$("li").find("[data-itemindex=3]")` means find an element that matches `[data-itemindex=3]` **inside** `li`. That's the problem. You dont want an element **inside**, you want `li` directly.

Comment: make sure your code is in [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: @TusharGupta i am doing this thing on ajax success, and tried DOM READY but still i am getting blank alert

Comment: @tusharGupta i put `winoria` in `<li>` earlier by javascript innerHTML. is that a reason its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS tag selector to locate the matching element/s within the DOM:

```
$("[data-itemindex=3]")
```

You can even do some more advanced selectors using a similar syntax:

```
[title~=flower] /* Selects all elements with a title attribute containing the word "flower" */
[lang|=en] /* Selects all elements with a lang attribute value starting with "en" */
a[src$=".pdf"] /* Selects every <a> element whose src attribute value ends with ".pdf" */
a[src^="https"] /* Selects every <a> element whose src attribute value begins with "https" */
```

[**Full documentation**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css%5fselectors.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $('li[data-itemindex="3"]').text();
```

or

```
 $('li[data-itemindex="3"]').html()
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/88XGA/)**

Comment: i am getting blank alert

Comment: yes, i tried it in ajax success, and that winoria i write on a earlier ajax success

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var data = $('li').data('itemindex', 3).text();
alert(data);
```