# Custom data-attribute selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, selector

Any idea why this happens …

```
    var attr = $(this).data('link');
    console.log(attr); // profile_following
    console.log($("a[data-target='profile_following']")); // found the object
    console.log($("a[data-target='+attr+']")); // [] empty
```

Inside of a click handler I have the lines above!
`console.log(attr);` successfully prints `profile_following`
However if I try to select a link with an attribute selector and this variable like this `console.log($("a[data-target='+attr+']"));` it can't find the element!

And the weirdest thing after all is if I hardcode the line like that `console.log($("a[data-target='profile_following']"));` it finds the object successfully.

Any idea why the same line wouldn't work with the `+attr+` inside the attribute selector?

Comment: You have to inject `attr` into the selector, so you have to delimit the prefix and suffix strings with double quotes (`"a[data-target='" + attr + "']"`). Also, this is a duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation to create a string with a value of `"a[data-target='profile_following']"`. You do that with:

```
$('a[data-target="'+attr+'"]');
```

In your example, `+attr+` is part of the string because you never closed and reopened your quotes.