# How to access divs all divs with a micro-data="3" property/value?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7.1.

I am trying to hightlight a column of divs if the column head div is hovered over.

If a div with the class of PC_ColumnHeadDiv has a data-col="3" attribute, I want to add a class to all of the divs with the PC_CellSpecValuesDiv class that have a data-col="3" attribute.

```
var PC_ColumnHeadDiv = $(".PC_ColumnHeadDiv"); 
var PC_CellSpecValuesDiv = $(".PC_CellSpecValuesDiv"); 

$(PC_ColumnHeadDiv).hover(
    function() {
        var C = $(this).data("col");
        $(PC_CellSpecValuesDiv).data("col:"+C).addClass("PC_Over");
    }, 
    function(){
        $(PC_CellSpecValuesDiv).removeClass("PC_Over");
    }   
);
```

The problem piece of code is this:

```
$(PC_CellSpecValuesDiv).data("col:"+C).addClass("PC_Over");
```

What I am trying to do here is find all of the divs CellSpecDivs where the data-col attribute is set to 3.

```
$(PC_CellSpecValuesDiv).data("col", 3).addClass("PC_Over");
$(PC_CellSpecValuesDiv).data("col").is(3).addClass("PC_Over");
$(PC_CellSpecValuesDiv).data("col").eq(3).addClass("PC_Over");
```

What's the right way to get this line to work?

**EDIT**

This line works. Is this the best way to code this, assuming the rest will stay the same?

```
$(PC_CellSpecValuesDiv).filter("[data-col='"+C+"']").addClass("PC_Over");
```

Comment: why do you wrap your jquery objects in another $()? for example `PC_CellSpecValuesDiv.hover(..` would suffice.

Comment: Or use find.
This one may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value

Comment: Or use find().
try this one.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
PC_CellSpecValuesDiv.filter('[data-col=' + C + ']').addClass('PC_over');
```

It will check the current set of matched element for the attribute "data-col". In case the element does not have that attribute, addClass() will have no effect, otherwise, the class name will be added.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/dEzUN/)**

---

Some notes on your code:

- this double work to do:

  ```
  var PC_ColumnHeadDiv = $(".PC_ColumnHeadDiv");
  $(PC_ColumnHeadDiv) // "PC_ColumnHeadDiv" is a already jquery object
  PC_ColumnHeadDiv.hover(...) // just use "PC_ColumnHeadDiv"
  ```

Comment: Okay, this works:  $(PC_CellSpecValuesDiv).filter("[data-col='"+C+"']").addClass("PC_Over");

Comment: @Didier - Inside `hover` OP is not using `$(this)` because OP wants to add class to `PC_CellSpecValuesDiv` which is not the one on which `hover` event is attached.

Comment: You're right, i did not see the slight difference. Made the correction.

Answer (score 1):

`$(PC_CellSpecValuesDiv).data("col", 3)` will set value 3 to data attribute `data-col`.
`$(PC_CellSpecValuesDiv).data("col")` will return the value of data attribute so calling `is(3)` on it will throw an error.

Try this.

```
PC_ColumnHeadDiv.hover(
    function() {
        var C = $(this).data("col");

        PC_CellSpecValuesDiv.filter('[data-col=' + C + ']').addClass("PC_Over");
    }, 
    function(){
        PC_CellSpecValuesDiv.removeClass("PC_Over");
    }   
);
```

`filter()` reduces the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.