# Find elements by custom data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I was wondering if there's a way to select an item (div,span,whatever..) using javascript with jQuery (+ jQuery UI lib) based on its data attribute value. For example, let's say I have:

```
<div class="b">Hi</div>
```

I then assign some data to it:

```
$('.b').data('myKey', 1234);
```

Then, I want to find a div (or multiple divs that) satisfy condition myKey = 1234 .
For example, like this:

```
var resultingElement = $('.b:data(myKey=1234)');
```

Is it possible by default, or do I have to implement this kind of selector myself?
And no, I don't want to use HTML5's visible data-* attributes for this.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value

Comment: Why do you want to select by jQuery's `.data()` *(which is not an attribute)*? It would be a terribly expensive operation compared to using an actual attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom pseudo-selector to make things easy: http://jsfiddle.net/g2xKB/1/.

```
$.expr.pseudos.data = $.expr.createPseudo(function(args) {
    var items = args.split(",");  // the arguments (key, value)

    $.each(items, function(i, item) {
        item = item.trim();
        var isString = /^['"]|['"]$/.test(item);
        item = item.replace(/^['"]|['"]$/g, "");  // remove quotes

        if(!isString) {
            item = +item;  // if no quotes, it's a number
        }

        items[i] = item;
    });

    return function(elem) {
        return $.data(elem, items[0]) === items[1];
    }
});
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
$(".b:data('myKey', 1234)").css("color", "red");
```

Comment: You can get a little performance bump if you do `$.data(elem, items[0])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $("div.b").filter(function() { 
          return $.data(this, "myKey") == 1234; 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultingElement = $('.b[data-myKey=1234]');
```

I'm not sure 100% sure, but I think there was an issue with camel-case selectors in data attributes at some point.

Comment: `.data()` does not change the actual `data-` attribute within the HTML, so it cannot be read in this way. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8e9UN/1/).