# How to get, set and select elements with data attributes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I'm having some trouble with data-attributes, I can't get anything to work for some reason so I must be doing something wrong:

Set:

```
$('#element').data('data1', '1'); //Actually in my case the data is been added manually
```

Does that make a difference?

Get:

```
$('#element').data('data1');
```

Select:

```
$('#element[data1 = 1]')
```

None of this works for me, am I making this up or how is it?

Comment: Maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094777/find-elements-by-custom-data-attribute-value/13094850#13094850.

Comment: [You shouldn't need to set the `[data-*]` attribute from within JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr/7262427#7262427).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

All of the answers are correct, but I want to state something that nobody else did.
The jQuery `data` method acts like a getter for html5 data attributes, but the setter does not alter the data-* attribute.
So, If you manually added the data (as is stated in your comment), then you can use a css attribute selector to select your element :

```
$('#element[data-data1=1]')
```

but if you have added (altered) the data via jQuery, then the above solution won't work.
Here's an example of this failure :

```
var div = $('<div />').data('key','value');
alert(div.data('key') == div.attr('data-key'));// it will be false
```

So the workaround is to filter the collection by checking the jQuery data value to match the desired one :

```
// replace key & value with own strings
$('selector').filter(function(i, el){
    return $(this).data('key') == 'value';
});
```

So, in order to overcome these issues, you need to use the html5 dataset attributes (via jQuery's `attr` methos) as getters and setters :

```
$('selector').attr('data-' + key, value);
```

or you can use a custom expression that filters jQuery internal `data` :

```
$.expr[':'].data = function(elem, index, m) {
    // Remove ":data(" and the trailing ")" from the match, as these parts aren't needed:
    m[0] = m[0].replace(/:data\(|\)$/g, '');
    var regex = new RegExp('([\'"]?)((?:\\\\\\1|.)+?)\\1(,|$)', 'g'),
    // Retrieve data key:
    key = regex.exec( m[0] )[2],
    // Retrieve data value to test against:
    val = regex.exec( m[0] );
    if (val) {
        val = val[2];
    }
    // If a value was passed then we test for it, otherwise we test that the value evaluates to true:
    return val ? $(elem).data(key) == val : !!$(elem).data(key);
};
```

and use it like :

```
$('selector:data(key,value)')
```

### Update

I know this thread is a few years old, but since it has some activity, it's worth mentioning that doing this using the `querySelector` dom API (with no need for jQuery) is quite trivial:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[attribute=value]')
```

Comment: this is where part of my problem was coming from I think what I'm actually looking for is just using attributes instead of data that way I don't have this problem, Thanks gion!

Comment: Thanks gion that answer is very complete and covers everything

Comment: Hi @gion_13 The filter method works for me but I cant seem to get the custom expression to work. Maybe due to jQuery changes? Would you mind having a look at http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/jqLa7q81/2/ ?

Comment: Apparently, after jQuery 1.7.2, the value that is returned for m is different than it was when gion_13 wrote the above custom expression. Here is a version that will work up to at least jQuery 2.1.3  http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/bbbb0shu/

Answer (score 10):

To reflect the values of the Attributes immediately in the DOM you can use `.attr()`

```
$('#element').attr('data-data1', '1');  // Sets the attribute

$('#element[data-data1="1"]') // Selects the element with data-data1 attribute'

$('#element').data('data1'); // Gets the value  of the attribute

$('#element').attr('data-data1'); // Gets the value  of the attribute
```

In plain Javascript you can try this

```
var elem = document.getElementById('element');

elem.setAttribute('data-data1', '1'); // Set the attribute

elem.getAttribute('data-data1'); // Gets the attribute
```

Comment: I think using the attr() is going to be the best way for me thanks it works now.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Set
$('#element').attr('data-value', 'value');
// Get
var value = $('#element').attr('data-value');
// Select
var elem = $('#element[data-value = "' +value+ '"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using ID selector so there is no need to use attribute selector, as data is a property and you are setting it using `data` method (*not attr method*) you cannot select the element using attribute selector, if you want to select the element only if it has `data1 === 1` you can use the `filter` method:

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
       // ...
       $('#element').filter(function() {
          return this.dataset.data1 == 1
          // return $(this).data('data1') == 1
       })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

> `dataset`: Allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element. It is a map of DOMString, one entry for each custom data attribute.

Comment: I just used an id selector in this made up example, I'm acually using a class selector. I will check that filter function out now, thanks for your help.