# Syntax for retrieving elements using data attribute

Tags: javascript, html

So I found a solution to what I need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275812/how-to-get-set-and-select-elements-with-data-attributes). The latest updated solution in that thread suggested using this line to retrieve elements by its data attribute:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[attribute=value]')
```

My question: that line hardcodes the `value` to the syntax. If I need to pass `value` from a variable, something like :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[attribute=]' = myVar)
```

For example, I want to select all elements with `data-genre` attribute set to `horror`. What is the correct syntax? The line below does not work.

```
let myVar = "horror"
document.querySelectorAll('[data-genre]' = myVar)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Traditionally, string concatenation is all you need. These days, this is best solved using [template string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), like this: `document.querySelectorAll(\`[attribute=]=${myVar}\`)`.