# Js find specific div with data atribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi im working on javascript chat and i want to append data to conversation that it belongs to
i have function to create new window and im setting a data attribute to each chat div

```
newWindow: function(name, id) {               
            if(!pushChatToArray(removeWhiteSpace(name))) return;                
            var div = htmlStructure(removeWhiteSpace(name));                
            setName(div, name);                
            setDataAttribute(div,"open","active");                
            setDataAttribute(div, "id", id);                
            $("body").append(div);                
            setCoordinates(div);
        },
```

im creating new windows like this

```
chatbox.newWindow("USERNAME", "28");
```

all i want is select the specific chat div by the data atribute id

this code im using when im writing somebody that i have focused,so i can get the id by selecting the div like this :

```
var id = $(this).closest(".chat").data("id");
```

but i want to find chat with specific id like this

```
var chatid = $("body").find(".chat[data-id=1]");
```

Thank you for help

Comment: can you show the code for `setDataAttribute()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var chatid = $('.chat').filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('id') == 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use as below

```
var chatid = $(".chat").find("[data-id='" + current + "']");
```

Also, I find more tip in 
[jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

You should use `attr("data-id")` than `data("id")`