# jQuery get element by data id

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am trying the get an `<li>` element by data attribute value (data-event_id=1282).

```
<div id="timeline">
    <ul>
        <li class="timeline-event">
             <div>Event Body</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

$el = $('#timeline ul').find("li.timeline-event").data('event_id');
console.log($el);    // returns 1282

$el = $('#timeline ul').find("li.timeline-event[data-event_id='1282']").html();
console.log($el);    // returns undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT - Solution**

The data is set using .data('event_id', '1282') elsewhere in the code.

jQuery is unable to get the data if it is set using .data().

I found the solution here using the filterByData function by @psycho brm. It works!

[jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value/15651670#15651670)

```
$.fn.filterByData = function(prop, val) {
    return this.filter(
        function() { return $(this).data(prop)==val; }
    );
}
```

I presume this must be a jQuery bug though?

Comment: There is no data-event_id attribute in the html you provided. Please update your sample code.

Comment: `.find()` never returns `undefined`, even when it doesn't find anything, it returns an empty jQuery collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Comment: How is it a duplicate of that? He's already using the correct selector. His problem must be something different -- he clearly hasn't posted the actual code.

Comment: @Barmar, your right, I missed .html() from the end. Then it returns undefined.

Comment: The data is set using .data() rather than inline, and that's what the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is set using .data('event_id', '1282') elsewhere in the code.

jQuery is unable to get the data if it is set using .data().

I found the solution here using the filterByData function. It works!

[jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value/15651670#15651670)

Comment: Add content of your refereed answer in your answer. otherwise your answer is nothing more that a link only answer which SO doesn't promote. It would be great if you provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I don't see data- attr in your html.

I have tried your code with adding data-event_id="1282" to li http://jsfiddle.net/dehisok/Wa5RG/

```
 <li class="timeline-event" data-event_id="1282">
```

It works!

Comment: Maybe, there are some js code before, that sets "data" (but not an attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Second id return undefined because you should provide him two options with li 
(i) class name
(ii) attribute

You should try to specify only on of them