# jQuery find element by data attribute value

Tags: jquery, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I have a few elements like below:

```
<a class="slide-link" href="#" data-slide="0">1</a>
<a class="slide-link" href="#" data-slide="1">2</a>
<a class="slide-link" href="#" data-slide="2">3</a>
```

How can I add a class to the element which has a `data-slide` attribute value of `0` (zero)?

I have tried many different solutions but nothing worked. An example:

```
$('.slide-link').find('[data-slide="0"]').addClass('active');
```

Any idea?

Comment: To explain things a little here, the reason why this doesn't work is because you are trying to find the descendants of `.slide-link` with the attribute of `[data-slide="0"]`.  Since something cannot be a descendant of itself, it doesn't have anything to return.  However, if you had a wrapper around these links, then this would have worked: `$('.slide-link-wrapper').find('[data-slide="0"]').addClass('active');`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4191386/292060

Answer (score 289, accepted):

Use [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('.slide-link[data-slide="0"]').addClass('active');
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/NT7jf/)</kbd>

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

it works down the tree

> Get the descendants of each element
>    in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Comment: My bad. I had tried that but in the wrong place (before adding my elements dynamically...). Anyway thanks for the effort! Works fine.

Comment: Wow! this solution is great! Had a problem for hours but this fixed it!

Answer (score 66):

You can also use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('.slide-link').filter('[data-slide="0"]').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 10):

I searched for a the same solution with a variable instead of the String.
I hope i can help someone with my solution :)

```
var numb = "3";
$(`#myid[data-tab-id=${numb}]`);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `andSelf()` method to get wrapper DOM contain then `find()` can be work around as your idea

```js
$(function() {
  $('.slide-link').andSelf().find('[data-slide="0"]').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="slide-link" href="#" data-slide="0">1</a>
<a class="slide-link" href="#" data-slide="1">2</a>
<a class="slide-link" href="#" data-slide="2">3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When looking to return multiple elements with different data attribute and different data attribute value were both **ARE NOT** always present

```
<p class='my-class' data-attribute1='1'></p>
<p class='my-class' data-attribute2='2'></p>

// data-attribute1 OR data-attribute2
$(".my-class").filter(`[data-attribute1="${firstID}"],[data-attribute2="${secondID}"]`);
```

When looking to return multiple elements with different data attribute and different data attribute value were both **ARE** always present

```
<p class='my-class' data-attribute1='1' data-attribute2='1'></p>
<p class='my-class' data-attribute1='1' data-attribute2='2'></p>

// data-attribute1 AND data-attribute2
$(".my-class").filter(`[data-attribute1="${firstID}"][data-attribute2="${secondID}"]`);
```

The placement of the **comma** is crucial to differentiate between finding with **OR** or an **AND** argument.

---

It also works for elements who have the same data attribute but with different attribute value

```
$(".my-class").filter(`[data-attribute1="${firstID}"],[data-attribute1="${secondID}"]`);
```

I was inspired by this post of [@omarjebari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510489/filter-by-multiple-data-attribute-elements/42489442#42489442) on stackoverflow.