# How to search for particular attribute and its value and assign some css on it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="1">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="yes"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>



<div id="2">
<table>

    <tr>
    <td><input giveBorder="yes"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="yes"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input giveBorder="yes"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>



<div id="3">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
    <td><input giveBorder="no"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
</body>
```

I'm iterating through all div's and now I need to search if entire table contains particular attribute and value. I need to search for `giveBorder="yes"` in whole table. If it any of the field contains that then I need to set border for that table and set border colour to red using jQuery.

After iterating through div I tried

```
var par = $(this).parent('table');
if(par.has('giveBorder="yes"').length === 0) {
    console.log("table has to be set red border");
}
```

How can I search for that attribute in enitre table, and set css for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery find element by data attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756777/jquery-find-element-by-data-attribute-value)

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong selector try the attribute selector:

```
var par = $(this).parent('table');
if(par.has('[giveBorder="yes"]')) {
console.log("table has to be set red border");
}
```

or

```
var par = $(this).parent('table');
if(par.find('[giveBorder="yes"]').length) {
console.log("table has to be set red border");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("input[giveBorder=yes]").parents("table").css("border", "1px solid red");
```

Comment: You should explain a little more your answer. Just from this, it's really hard to tell how or why your answer works.