# jQuery select a button using data-value attribute

Tags: jquery, html, button

I am trying to select a button using the `data-value` attribute. I have set a variable for the `data-value` when I click a button. How do I further use it when I click it again to select the particular button?

**HTML**

```
    <button data-value="1" class="key">1
        <span>. , !</span>
    </button>
</td>
<td>
    <button data-value="2" class="key">2
        <span>a b c</span>
    </button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#phone").find("button").mouseup(function(event){
        var button_pressed = $(event.currentTarget).data("value");
        $("#result").val(t9($("#result").val(),button_pressed));

    });
});
```

Comment: see this link. it is a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/a/4191718/2951561

Comment: What is the t9 function please in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQueryUI's **[`:data()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/)** selector for this:

```
$("#phone").find("button:data(value)").mouseup(...);
```

Note: Unless jQueryUI is already a dependancy, this is probably not what you need. Not worth it to include just for this selector. You can however, check and use the source for just this or write a custom selector perhaps.

Comment: Clarification: That's jQuery *UI*, not jQuery

Comment: @RGraham - Ahh yes. Its jQuery UI. Thanks for pointing out. So unless jQUI is a requirement, this answer is invalid. Not worth it to include just for this selector. You can however, check and use the source for just this or write a custom selector perhaps.