# jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value (v2)?

Tags: jquery

I've read this, so this is not a duplicate. All the solutions proposed don't work [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Here's what I'm doing on the console of Chrome:

```
$('table#ct_ennemies_2 td').each(function() {
    var t=$(this).data('to-shoot'); console.log(t == "1")
});
```

Then I get a result: one cell is marked with `data('to-shoot') = 1`. Great. Now if I try to find by data attribute like this:

```
$('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[to-shoot="1"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this))
});
```

I get an empty result:

```
[]
```

Same if I try

```
$('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[to-shoot=1]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this))
});
```

I get an empty result:

```
[]
```

Here's what you can do on the console log of Chrome:

```
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td').first().data('to-shoot','1');
[<td ...blablah >@</td>]
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td').first().data();
Object {toShoot: "1"}
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td').first().data('to-shoot');
"1"
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[to-shoot="1"]');
[]
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[to-shoot]');
[]
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[data-to-shoot]').each(function() { console.log($(this)) });
[]
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[data-to-shoot=1]').each(function() { console.log($(this)) });
[]
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[data-to-shoot="1"]').each(function() { console.log($(this)) });
[]
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[data-toShoot="1"]').each(function() { console.log($(this)) });
[]
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[toShoot="1"]').each(function() { console.log($(this)) });
[]
>> $('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[toShoot=1]').each(function() { console.log($(this)) });
[]
>> td = $('#ct_ennemies_2 td').filter(function() {
>>   return $(this).data('to-shoot') === 1;
>> });
[]
>> td
[]
```

My question is: how to apply properly a filter that returns the expected `td` which contains the data `to-shoot=1`?

Comment: If you do `var t = $(this).attr('data-to-shoot');` does it return the same thing.

Comment: I don't understand why the linked stackoverflow question doesn't help you, it is the normal way to do it. Maybe if you made a jsfiddle we could see why nothing is returned with your selector, but `$('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[data-to-shoot=1]')` as Kyle suggested should be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` attributes begin with `data-`

```
$('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[data-to-shoot=1]')
```

**Note**: this only works if you manually added the data attribute in the markup or via `attr('data-to-shoot', 1)`. If it was applied via `data('to-shoot', 1)` you will need to use [Bills'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23161306/640577) answer.

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2Ef9/1/)

Fiddle contents:

```
<div class="test"></div>

$(function(){
  var d = $('div.test');

  d.data('to-shoot', 1);

  alert($('div[data-to-shoot=1]').length); // 0

  d.attr('data-to-shoot', 1);

  alert($('div[data-to-shoot=1]').length); // 1

  var divs = $('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('to-shoot') == 1; 
  });

  alert(divs.length); // 1
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work (I've updated my question with samples tried)

Comment: @OlivierPons see my edit as well as [Bill's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23161306/640577) answer for a solution.

Comment: You're right, your solution works with `$('table#ct_ennemies_2 td').first().attr('data-to-shoot','1');` then get it with `$('table#ct_ennemies_2 td[data-to-shoot="1"]')`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `filter` since `.data` does not apply the data to an actual attribute, but an inner hash table.

```
var $td = $('#ct_ennemies_2 td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('to-shoot') === 1;
});
```

Also, pet peeve, the `table` before your `id` selector isn't needed.

Comment: It doesn't work (I've updated my question with samples tried)

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer since OP added the attribute via `data('to-shoot', '1')`