# How to find div that has matching data attr then remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, jquery-selectors

Here is my attempt that doesn't seem to be working:

```
$('container').find("[data-slider='" + one + "']").removeClass('hidden');
```

Here is the full function that is wrapped in a document. ready function

```
$("#service-icon").on('click', function(){

       var $this = $(this);
       event.preventDefault();

       $this.addClass('ease-transition').toggleClass('active-slider-btn');

       $(".page-wrapper").find("[data-slider='" + one + "']").toggleClass("hidden");


 });
```

The error that I am getting is:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: one is not defined"

Comment: if container is a class, that should be `$('.container')`. If it is an id, it should be `$('#container')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Comment: i took a look at that page before posting my question but that didnt seam to solve my issue, also i change it to $(".page-wrapper") instead of $("container") but dosent seem to solve it, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check:

1. Is `container` a class or id? If so you'll need to add a `.` or `#` respectively
2. That the expression in the `.find()` function returns what you're expecting

Can you post a link to a JSFiddle or something?

[I have a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/qEDPL/2/) that is similar to your situation.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div data-slider="1" class="hidden">1</div>
    <div data-slider="2">2</div>
</div>

<button id="show-1">show slider 1</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var one = "1";

$("#show-1").click(function(e){
    $(".container").find("[data-slider='" + one + "']").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: I changed it to $('.page-wrapper') but its still not working, anything else i could do??

Comment: i just forgot to wrap one with quotes...... Thank you very much for all your guys help i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this has to work:

```
   $('.page-wrapper').find("[data-slider='" + one + "']").removeClass('hidden');
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/sNp7x/2/

Maybe the data attribute is set via javascript as well, so you have to be aware of the timing?!

Comment: the error that im getting is "Uncaught ReferenceError: one is not defined ". I have no clue why i am getting that error...

Comment: one has to be defined, as the error says, like so:
    var one = 'test';
    $('.page-wrapper').find("[data-slider='" + one + "']").removeClass('hidden');