# Using jQuery variables to select data-* HTML 5 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can select an `HTML5` element by `data-*` element with:

```
$("[data_value='5']")
```

However, I'd like to replace the `5` with a jQuery variable.  When I do, I am no longer able to select the element.  For example:

```
> $("[data-uid='4']")
[<div class=​"eventInfo individual" data-uid=​"4">​…​</div>​]
> var uid = 4
> $("[data-uid=uid]")
[]
```

How do I make a selection using a variable?

Comment: String concatenation. Given `$("[data-uid=uid]")`, how could it possibly know which if any `uid` should use the variable?

Comment: This question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("[data-uid=" + uid + "]")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `+` to do so.

JS:

```
 var uid_var = 4;
 $("[data-uid="+ uid_var +"]")
```