# using jquery to select data-letter

Tags: jquery

```
<div data-letter='1'>1</div>
<div data-letter='2'>2</div>
<div data-letter='3'>3</div>
```

Is any way to select element by data-letter?
ex. I want to select data-letter "2"

Comment: [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute selector

```
$("[data-letter='2']").html()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").each(function(){
  if($(this).attr("data-letter")=="2")
  {
    alert($(this).html());
  }
});
```

OR

If there are many div's with `data-letter = 2` ,then do as :

```
$("div[data-letter='2']").each(function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

if there is only one div with `data-letter = 2` ,then do as :

```
$("div[data-letter='2']").html()
```