# Angularjs: how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

I've got the following directive:

```
template: '<div data-div="outer"><div data-div="inner"></div></div>',
link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
       var outer = elem.find('[data-div="outer"]');
       var inner = elem.find('[data-div="inner"]');
       outer.css({
           'background': 'red',
           'width': "100%",
           'height': "100%",
       });
       inner.css({
           'background': 'blue',
           'width': "50%",
           'height': "100%",
       });
    }
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/), i tried these selectors. but im using jQLite, not JQuery.

so, how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?

http://plnkr.co/edit/FeJWvwnKjOZwAIABigtA?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `querySelector()` (or `querySelectorAll()` for multiples) to get a similar `find()` behavior when using jqLite...

```
function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var outer = angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('[data-div="outer"]'));
    var inner = angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('[data-div="inner"]'));
    outer.css({
       'background': 'red',
       'width': "100%",
       'height': "100%",
    });
    inner.css({
       'background': 'blue',
       'width': "50%",
       'height': "100%",
    });
}
```

Comment: `elem.find` in plunker should be `angular.element`... `querySelector()` returns the raw DOM element and all that is needed is to turn it back into a jqLite object.

Comment: Just `angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('[data-div="outer"]'))` http://plnkr.co/edit/Xi5q1F4iTc0qbjWEVGrK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j8N6sy91HEiwAHYRV2Fe?p=preview)

In angular, you rarely ever have to use jQuery selectors to find elements. 
Angular will walk the DOM tree and find the directives for you.

All you have to do is implement the directives:

```
app.directive('div', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            if(attr.div == 'outer') {
               element.css({
                  'background': 'red',
                  'width': "100%",
                  'height': "100%",
                });
            }
            if(attr.div == 'inner') { 
               element.css({
                  'background': 'blue',
                  'width': "50%",
                  'height': "100%",
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If you need further interactions with the parent directive, angular makes that easy to do too. You just have include a *require* attribute to your directive definition, and the parent controller will be injected as the 4th parameter to your child directive's link function:

```
app.directive ('parent', function() {
      return  {
         ...
         controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
             function doSomething() {
             }
         } 
      }
});

app.directive('child, function() {
      return {
           restrict: 'A',
           require: '^parent',  // child directive requires a parent directive
           link: function(scope, element, attr, parentController) {
               // access to the parent controller
               parentController.doSomething();
           }
      }
});
```

Comment: Then include jQuery, and use it:P