# Why isn't this jQuery selector finding anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div inside a div. This inner div has a data attribute. I tried to apply the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value) question to find the inner div, but am having no luck. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var content = $('#mapElements').find('.mapMarker [data-depotid="b04b4184"]').data('depotguid');

$('#result').text(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='mapElements'>
  <div class="mapMarker" data-depotid="b04b4184">This is the text from mapMarker, and if the depotID appears below this text the code works!</div>
</div>

<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrong Selector for targeting `.mapMarker` element. Use:

```
var content = $('#mapElements').find('.mapMarker[data-depotid="b04b4184"]').data('depotguid');
                                             //^space not required here
```

You can also narrow down the selector for child element to:

```
var content = $('#mapElements').find('.mapMarker').data('depotguid');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(" #mapElements > .mapMarker[data-depotid='b04b4184'] ");
```

or directly

```
$(".mapMarker [data-depotid='b04b4184']");
```