# jQuery, how to find an element by attribute NAME?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found many example finding elements by attribute value BUT not with name. I want to find all elements (can be link, button, anything) with the attribute containing `deleteuserid`. I tried this:

```
console.log($('[deleteuserid!=""]'));
```

but this find "everything" which not even containing the `deleteuserid` attribute...

something like this: [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value) expect that I dont have a concrete value (in other words, I want to find `$("ul").find("[data-slide=*]");`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply use `deleteuserid` instead of `deleteuserid!=""` like following.

```
console.log($('[deleteuserid]'));
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use the jquery attribute selector to search by name.

```
console.log($('[name="deleteuserid"]'));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can search by simple $('[name="deleteuserid"]')

```js
console.log($('[name="deleteuserid"]'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p name="deleteuserid">

</p>
<div name="deleteuserid">

</div>
<i name="deleteuserid"></i>
<b></b>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "*[name*='deleteuserid']" ).addClass('iFoundyou');
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqxsff3m/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

My demo:
All my selects have id="<f_field_name>"

```html
    <select id="f_type" />
    <select id="f_employee" />
```

```js
   $('[name="form_monitoria_ligacoes"]').find('[id^="f_"]')
```