# jQuery find all attr rel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a this select dropdown:

```
<select id="category">
  <option value="cat1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="cat2">Category 2</option>
</select>
```

and I have this code that everytime I select something form the dropdown it takes the value and find the same class and show it on the last line

```
$('#category').change(function () {
    var selected_category = $(this).val();

    $('#sub-category').find('.option').hide();
    $('#sub-category').find('.'+selected_category).show();                              
});
```

I just want to change instead of class so it will find the attribute rel

** **edited** **

Comment: You just changed your question in a way that invalidates existing answers to some degree. You originally asked to find all option elements w/ a rel attribute of "sub-cat1".

Comment: Yes sorry, can you help me with that? I appreciate your help!

Comment: What does "option tags with the rel values" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Comment: Are you looking to find any option tag that _also_ has a rel attribute as well? Or something else? Please be specific.

Comment: I edit the question, let me know if it's more clear

Comment: You have completely changed your question twice now.

Comment: I know, so sorry can you help me?

Comment: You **can not hide** `<option>` tag. It is not supported cross browser. Notably IE does not support it. Choices are remove or disable

Comment: Wow, thanks, really important stuff, I'll try to find a solution for that

Answer (score 2):

You definitely don't need jQuery for this. Here's the code to find all option tags with a rel attribute of "sub-cat1":

`document.querySelectorAll('option[rel="sub-cat1"]')`

The above will work in IE8 and up, which should satisfy all browsers you need to support. The jQuery solution is similar, and uses the same selector string:

`$('option[rel="sub-cat1"]')`

Furthermore, you don't need to add a class of "option". Simply select using the option tag name.

Comment: Sorry that I changed the question

Answer (score 1):

There can be an alternate way to your answer.
Using jquery try ,

```
$       (".classname").each(function(){  
//iterate over similar *classname* elements one by one
$(this).someFunc(); //it will help you to preform operation at current value while iteration
});
```

With ***rel***  if you want to iterate over *rel tag values* , try

```
$("[rel='sub-cat-1']").each(function(){
//Some operation
});
```