# How to get the span tag which has particular attribute value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to get the span tag which has the particular attribute value.

This is my html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="languagelist">
  <li ng-repeat="(id, langName) in items" ng-click="switchLanguage(id,langName,$event)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" langAttr={{langName}}> </span>
    <a>{{langName}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my JS file i have `$scope.language` which has the preferred language.
`$scope.language` might be `"English", "Spanish","Japanese","French"`.

Now in my javascript, I need to get the span tag which has the `langAttr`(Atrribute) which equals to my  `$scope.language`.

How can i use jquery to get the span tag whose attribute value is equal to the `$scope.language`

I can get all the span tags like this `$("#languagelist span")`

How can i filter or find the span tag which has the required attribute ?

If anyone knows any simple way, please do help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: depends on what you want. The tagging of jquery stuff is based on css. If you know your css you can do it easily. e.g. `$("span.glyphicon")` will get you all spans with glyphicon

Comment: Add angularjs tag, let those people also know this question

Comment: `$('#languagelist span[langAttr="' + $scope.language + '"]')` should do the trick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)