# Jquery - Selector wont go deeper

Tags: jquery, unrecognized-selector

What I already got by JQuery Selector on using:

```js
$("li[data-uid='"+dialogItem.uid+"']")
```

is:

```html
<li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-first k-last" data-uid="b3e03746-c914-49a6-a95f-756de2d97a1b" aria-selected="false" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true">
  <div class="k-top k-bot">…</div>
  <ul class="k-group" role="group" style="display: block;">
    <li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-last" data-uid="cdd29906-aa64-43bc-b727-950a32ce5c00" aria-selected="true" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true" id="dialogtreediv_tv_active">…</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I want to get the data_uid cdd29906-aa64-43bc-b727-950a32ce5c00 from the most inner "li" but as soon as I add the element "ul" to the selector (to go one step deeper) I don't get anything back: $("li[data-uid='"+dialogItem.uid+"'] **ul**" (same with "> ul" or "ul:first-child")

The weird thing: If I add "div" (instead of "ul") it goes into the div element.

What am I doing wrong or is Jquery unable to handle different element types on the same hierarchy (in this case "div" and "ul")?

Comment: Could you post the actual code you're having trouble with? It's hard to tell when you describe it in text.

Comment: What I want to do: $("li[data-uid='"+dialogItem.uid+"'] > ul > li")

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/yx30qL4k/

Comment: Can you confirm the value of dialogItem.uid.  It's not "cdd..." but some chance?

Comment: Seems like it should work? Inspect your HTML, it could be it's invalid and has been changed by the browser

Comment: @Jonny See this one: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/yx30qL4k/1/ it gets the inner `li` data attribute.

Comment: what does your dialogItem.uid hold .. can you post you code

Comment: You'll need to create a [mcve] as there are no issues with the code as-provided.   (as also shown by Barmar's fiddle).  Do you have any third-party plugins acting on the html?  Check the html in the browser/view source.

Comment: Wow, many answers in a view minutes, thanks all! @Barmar: I can see your  example working as it should. If I add the alert with length output I still got 0.
I'm using KendoUI Framework. The HTML code above is created by the Widget Treeview, that works in general.
dialogItem.uid holds 80692773-f0ac-46a6-aa5f-9ed3146bd0ec and that is fine since $("li[data-uid='"+dialogItem.uid+"']") shows the correct output.
Thanks all, I have to do some local investigations then, so weird.

Comment: Ugh, *kendo*, should have recognised the `k-` classes.  I feel for you.

Answer (score 0):

$("ul").find("[data-uid='" + dialogItem.uid + "']");

For more info and other techniques visit this thread [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Comment: This is wrong. The `ul` is inside the element with `data-uid=dialogItem.uid`.

Comment: OP is already finding the element based on the data attribute.

Comment: I don't see how the ```ul``` being inside is a problem. It finds any ul with an element that has data-uid in the document.

Comment: @MateuszMysiak the`ul` being inside is not a problem... usually.  You've "fixed" `ul>[data]`, OP has problem `[data]>ul`.  OP has some other problem that is not obvious in their code.  This does not answer the problem of "[data]>ul".

Comment: Thanks for you post even if you didn't understand my problem and posting a link that doesn't cover the problem.