# How to clear an input fields value based on a data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple input fields where the user can select a date time, the only difference between these fields is the data-department attribute.

```
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="datetime-local" class="StartTime" data-department="2" name="bdaytime">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="datetime-local" class="StartTime" data-department="3" name="bdaytime">
                </div>
```

I want to be able to clear the value in an input field based on the data-department attribute.

How can I clear the value of an input field based on the class and data-department?

So for example if I want to be able to clear just a single input field where class equals StartTime and data-department equals 2?

I tried using the below code however it didn't work.

```
    $('input:datetime-local').find('data-department' = 2).val('');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Comment: $('input.StartTime[data-department="2"]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clearing department 2

```
$('input[data-department="2"]').val('');
```

Here you go with a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y75tgzkb/

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('input[data-department="2"]').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="datetime-local" class="StartTime" data-department="2" name="bdaytime">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="datetime-local" class="StartTime" data-department="3" name="bdaytime">
</div>

<button>
  Clear
</button>
```

In the code I'm only clearing **department 2**.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This selector should work:

```
$('input[type="datetime-local"][data-department="2"]').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear single input field check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y75tgzkb/2/

To clear multiple input fields,give any commen `data-department` to your code like `data-department="11"`,`data-department="12".
Here`1` is common then you can proceed like this

```
$( "input[data-department*='1']" ).val('');
```

working fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/y75tgzkb/1/