# Get a div id from a div that has a specific data value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have this...

```
<div class="container" id="continingStuff">
    <div class="someClass" id="notLookingForThis" data="dataValue1">
        Stuff
    </div>
    <div class="someClass" id="lookingForThis" data="dataValue2">
        Stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

and I want to get the `id` of the `div` thats data value is `dataValue2`, how can I do that with jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: This is not a question, and has no code, no further investigating. Please, try to read something about Jquery selectors and read the guide for creating good questions on StackOverflow.
Selectors -> https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: It technically is a question. It does have markup code and this is me investigating. I didn’t know what a "jQuery selector” was, so how was I to know that I should be reading about that, without asking someone first? You see, going onto google and typing this question in whilst not having a mental model of the scenario is pointless. That is why this site exists, check out their motto.  It is a good question because it clearly states the outcome I desire. I outline a scenario and clearly outlined what I want as a result. But thank you very much for taking the time to try and raise your stock.

Comment: Refering to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: 

Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:

Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: What if you can’t even start and have no idea how to even start solving a problem? Should people like that just not even bother trying to ask questions? And again, stop trying to raise your stock by using me, this isn’t “homework”, “mate”.

Comment: mate, it´s easier for me to gain points answering your question, but I´m just trying to help you learning how to use the site. Googling your question , this is the second result: 
Get a div id from a div that has a specific data value -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value Just exposing what seems to be a no further work instead of asking.

Comment: I know how to use the site. I have asked questions before and those questions have included examples of my efforts. This question had no examples because I had no idea how to even start. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can use this selector:

```
var id = $("div[data='dataValue2']").attr('id');
```

Here's working a code snippet:

```js
var id = $("div[data='dataValue2']").attr('id');
console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="continingStuff">
    <div class="someClass" id="notLookingForThis" data="dataValue1">
       Stuff
    </div>
    <div class="someClass" id="lookingForThis" data="dataValue2">
       Stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get element, then you can use [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get id of the element.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = $('div[data=“dataValue2”]').attr('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=“container” id=“continingStuff”>

 <div class=“someClass” id=“notLookingForThis” data=“dataValue1”>
  Stuff
 </div>

 <div class=“someClass” id=“lookingForThis” data=“dataValue2”>
  Stuff
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz this isn't a question. This is an answer. LOL.

Comment: jahhahahha :) LOL I wrote where it was not the place!!! Nice edit !! :) removed downvote!!! ;) sorry for my mistake!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this  for your code

`var id = $('*[data="dataValue2"]').attr('id');`