# Jquery - add data with to element and get element by added data

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

Can i get and element by data added with jquery? For Example

```js
   function first() {
    var modal_body = $('.modal-body');
    modal_body.data('id',4)
   }
   
   function second() {
    var modal_body = $('.modalbody[data-id=4]');
   }
```

I've already tried this example, but it doesn't work because the element doesn't have data-id. Jquery saves data internally and creates an empty object called `$.cache`.

Is there any posibility to get the element, which contains data added with Jquery?

Comment: change `$('.modalbody[data-id=4]');` to `$('.modal-body[data-id=4]');`

Comment: @AlivetoDie That's an attribute selector, but there's no `data-id` attribute in the markup, hence this doesn't work.

Comment: @Andreas that suggest dup is the exact opposite of your earlier comment - there is no data- attribute.

Comment: @freedomn-m The question has answers that match exactly this requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15651670/402037, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22209579/402037

Comment: @Andreas thanks for clarifying - the question itself is not the same, nor is the answer - but as you say, there are suitable and relevant responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

As you said, the data properties are added internally by jQuery. The only way to achieve what you want is to set attributes directly:

```
   function first() {
     var modal_body = $('.modal-body');
     modal_body.attr('data-id',4)
   }

   function second() {
    var modal_body = $('.modal-body[data-id=4]'); // note: fixed .modalbody to .modal-body
   }
```

Which makes it available as `.data('id')` as well.

Another alternative would be to use `.filter()`:

```
   function first() {
     var modal_body = $('.modal-body');
     modal_body.data('id',4)
   }
   function second() {
    var modal_body = $('.modal-body').filter(function () {
      return $(this).data('id') === 4;
    });
   }
```

Demo below.

```js
(() => {
  var modal_body = $('div.modal-body');
  modal_body.attr('data-id', 4)

  console.log('found using attr:', $('.modal-body[data-id=4]').length);
})();

(() => {
  var modal_body = $('span.modal-body');
  modal_body.data('id', 4)

  console.log('found using filter:', $('span.modal-body').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('id') === 4;
  }).length);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-body">modal-body</div>

<span class="modal-body">modal-body</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, Few minutes ago I found the post width the filter function.

Answer (score 1):

Not with a single selector, but certainly using `.filter()`:

```js
$("#x").data("data", "a");
$("#y").data("data", 4);

var x2 = $("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("data") != null;
});

var y4 = $("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("data") === 4;
});

console.log("Divs:", $("div").length, "With ID:", x2.length, "With id==4:", y4.length);
x2.addClass("box");
y4.addClass("box4");
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid #CCC; }
.box { border: 1px solid green; }
.box4 { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='x'>x</div>
<div id='y'>y</div>
<div id='z'>y</div>
```

*Update:* check for explicit data value, not just any

Comment: Already marked the post as duplicate. The `filter` function solved the problem. Thanks