# remove select element with specific attr value

Tags: jquery

I try to remove a specific select element with attibute value called data-wr. So then I can remove it from the dom.

Html:

```
<div class='tcat'>
  <select>..</select>
  <select data-wr="1">..</select>
  <select>..</select>
  <select data-wr="12">..</select>
  <select data-wr="3">..</select>
</div>
```

Below JQuery removes all the select elements:

```
var rw= 12;
$('select[data-wr != ' + rw + ']')
```

But it has to be equal to rw's value:

```
var rw= 12;
$('select[data-wr = ' + rw + ']')
```

above does not work.

I also tried from this question:
[jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

```
var s = $(".tcat").find("select[data-wr='" + rw + "']"); 
s.remove();
```

also filter isn't working:

```
var s =$('.tcat').find($('select').filter('[data-wr=' + rw + ']'))
```

I could not make it work.

Comment: in the question you reported there is at least an answer using **filter** function. Use one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to put some quotes around rw.

```js
function remove() {
  let rw = 12;
  $(".tcat select[data-wr='" + rw + "']").remove();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tcat">
  <select data-wr="12">
    <option value="1"> Hello</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button onclick="remove()">
remove
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's better like that (to find the attribute) :

```
const s = $(".tcat").find("select").attr("[data-wr='" + rw + "']");
```