# Get innerHtml by data-id

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have many `<li>` with specific `data-id`, want to get innerHtml of first `<Div>`

For Example on this sample, it would to be: "World"

```
<li class="dd-item" data-id="1123066248731271" data-slug="" data-new="1" data-deleted="0"><div class="dd-handle">World</div> <span class="button-delete btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" title="Delete" data-owner-id="1123066248731271"> <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span><span class="button-edit btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right" title="Edit" data-owner-id="1123066248731271"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
```

This is my code, that doesn't help:

```
var target = $('[data-id="1123066248731271"]');
alert(target.firstChild.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Comment: Probably jQuery doesn’t have a .firstChild property.  What error message do you get?

Comment: The `innerHTML` of that element would not be "World"; it would be `<div class="dd-handle">World</div> <span class="button-delete btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" title="Delete" data-owner-id="1123066248731271"> <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span><span class="button-edit btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right" title="Edit" data-owner-id="1123066248731271"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>` You likely want the text, which you get using the [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need?

Being a jquery element, you can use `find()` method to find all the `div` elements inside him, with `first()`, you get the first element, finally, with `html()`, you get its content.

```js
var target = $('[data-id="1123066248731271"]');
alert(target.find('div').first().html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="dd-item" data-id="1123066248731271" data-slug="" data-new="1" data-deleted="0"><div class="dd-handle">World</div> <span class="button-delete btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" title="Delete" data-owner-id="1123066248731271"> <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span><span class="button-edit btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right" title="Edit" data-owner-id="1123066248731271"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.querySelector('[data-id="1123066248731271"]').textContent
```

Comment: This might work as well. But note that it will probably return the inner textual content of your *entire* `li` element, not just the first `div`. (But if only the first `div` contains textual content that would be OK, I guess.)

Answer (score 2):

first problem `$('[data-id="1123066248731271"]')` returned a object of all elements with [data-id="1123066248731271"]. for target the first element, you need add [0] after : `$('[data-id="1123066248731271"]')[0]`

now if you want target the div element you need specify div into $ like: `$('[data-id="1123066248731271"] div')[0]`. Now you got the first div and you can get innerHTML with : `target.innerHTML`

The full code :

```
var target = $('[data-id="1123066248731271"] div')[0];
alert(target.innerHTML);
```

and without Jquery ( more simply i think ) :

```
var target = document.querySelector('[data-id="1123066248731271"] div');
alert(target.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to use `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild`?

Or you could use the CSS selector `[data-id="1123066248731271"] > div:first-child`:

```
  var target = $('[data-id="1123066248731271"] > div:first-child');
  alert(target.innerHTML);
```

Edit:

I noticed a translation error. I don't use jQuery myself, so instead of `$` I used `document.querySelector`. But the behavior of `$` corresponds to `document.querySelectorAll` instead. Sorry...

This should work fine:

```
  var target = $('[data-id="1123066248731271"] > div:first-child')[0];
  alert(target.innerHTML);
```

or this:

```
  var target = document.querySelector('[data-id="1123066248731271"] > div:first-child');
  alert(target.innerHTML);
```

As a non-jQuery user, I personally prefer the latter.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me, it's show "undefined", anyway thanks.