# How do I highlight a specific day on fullcalendar v.3.1 js/c# retrieved by gotodate function?

Tags: html, jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/*var event_list = $('#event_list');*//*gil70l*/
    //$(document).ready(function () {
    //
    $("#btnsearch").click(function () {
        var res = $("#txtSearch").val();
        res = res.substring(0,19);
        date = moment(res, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
        alert(date);
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
        $('.fc-day[data-date="' + date + '"]').css('background-color', "red");
        //$('#calendar').find('.fc-day-number[data-date="' + date + '"]').css('background-color', '#FAA732');
      
    })
```

but I cannot highlight the day on which I position myself with the function 'gotoDate'.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4191718/13604954
similar as **$(".fc-day").find('[data-date="' + date + '"]')**

Comment: thanks, but i haven't found a solution to my problem

Comment: I also tried:$(".fc-day").find('[data-date="' + date + '"]').addClass("fc-highlight"); but nothing.

Comment: **$('.fc-day[data-date="' + date + '"]')** maybe return more than one elements.
try to console.log() like this **console.log($('.fc-day[data-date="' + date + '"]'))**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.fc-day[data-date="' + date + '"]'
```

...in here you'd need to put the `date` in yyyy-mm-dd format, as this would match what you see if you look at the generated fullCalendar HTML and see what's there already. Currently you're letting momentJS use its default string format output which would look something like

```
 Wed Aug 25 2021 10:26:36 GMT+0100
```

I expect that

```
$('.fc-day[data-date="' + date.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + '"]'
```

will work better.

Comment: Ok thanks, it works.But if I wanted to color the single event, how could I do?

Comment: I tried '$('.fc-event-dot[data-date="' + date.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + '"]').css('background-color', '#a31a5c');',but nothing

Comment: If you have a specific event you want to highlight, you can set its properties (including colour-related properties) by updating it through the fullCalendar API: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/updateEvent . P.S. I ahve answered the question as you gave it, so please mark it as accepted and/or upvote it. If you have a different question, please make a new post to ask that separately - thanks :-)

Comment: P.S. I've no idea where you got the `.fc-event-dot` bit from, that isn't a thing in fullCalendar 3, at least not by default anyway (and in later versions, it doesn't carry the date with it as a data attribute). Examining the generated HTML of fullCalendar would show you this, and remove any need for guesswork :-)