# How to use jQuery to find the div in which threre is a specific data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a div with class `dis-section` in which there are other multiple div. In each subdiv with class `list` there is an attribute `dpos`.

```
<div class="dis-section">
    <div class="col-12 list">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" data-dpos="10">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 list">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" data-dpos="11">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 list">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" data-dpos="12">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Is there a way in jQuery or in JavaScript to find the subdiv `<div class="col-12 list">...</div>` containing the attribute e.g. `dpos=12`

Comment: Pretty easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value

Comment: `$('div.dis-section').find('div.list:has(div[data-dpos])')` :has() selector https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/