# JQuery On Click with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting element by data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute)

I'm trying to listen to when an element with a certain data attribute is clicked but I can't seem to get the on click working and I'm sure its something easy on my part that I'm missing. I have

```
<a href="/home" data-spinner="true" />
```

```
$.data('record').click(function() {
         //Do Action
});
```

I have that with variations. My question is, how can I use an data attribute with on click?

Comment: This is not how `$.data` works. I recommend to read the documentation, before you blindly try things: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/. It saves a lot of time!

Answer (score 50):

Easy solution to your problem: (Not tested)

```
$('a[data-spinner="true"]').click(function(event) {

});
```

Comment: $('a[data-spinner="true"]').on('click', function(){ }); or $(document).on('click', 'a[data-spinner="true"]', function(){ }); if html dynamically added to DOM

Answer (score 22):

This selects all elements with the data-spinner attribute, regardless of the value of the attribute.

```
    $( "[data-spinner]" ).live( "click", function () {
        console.log('clicked');
    } );
```

Comment: `.live()` removed from later versions of jQuery, use `.on()` instead; https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 12):

The following code binds `click` event to all `<a>` elements which have `data-spinner` [attribute equal to](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) `true`:

```
$("a[data-spinner='true']").click(function() {
    //Do Acction
});
```