# Jquery add selected class to li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have following `ul li` that display categories name:

```
<ul>
<li class="selected" data-tab-id="0"></li>
<li data-tab-id="12">...</li>
<li data-tab-id="3">...</li>
<li data-tab-id="15">...</li>
<li data-tab-id="7">...</li>
</ul>
```

The javascript scripts as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cat_id = '<?=$this->catid?>'

$(document).ready(function () {

});
</script>
```

Currently the page at index so first `li data-tab-id="0"` will be selected class also `var cat_id` will be return nothing. Now when user navigate to another tab such as `data-tab-id="12"`, `var cat_id` will be return value of 12, how can i remove class selected from default li and replace it to `data-tab-id="12"`. Thanks

Comment: im not sure what you mean but this is how you add classes $('li').addClass('selected'); and $('.selected').removeClass('selected');

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting element by data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute)

Comment: Just a side note, I noticed you are using PHP by seeing the `short tags` above in your code. Be mindful of these tags as they are not available on every installation of PHP. It is a setting in the `php.ini` file that may not be turned on in all installations. This could cause errors when it comes to portability of your code. Stick with `<?php` to ensure compatibility across the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` to add and remove class respectively.
try this

**updated**

```
var cat_id = '<?=$this->catid?>';
$('li').removeClass('selected'); 
 $('li').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('data-tab-id')==cat_id){
    $(this).addClass('selected'); 
  }
})
```

**updated**  without using loop..

```
var cat_id = '<?=$this->catid?>';
$('li').removeClass('selected');
$('li[data-tab-id='+cat_id+']').addClass('selected');
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/LnB73/)

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/LnB73/1/)

Comment: sure...let me now if any problem

Comment: This answer is **bad**, there is no need for the loop! Nothing like reinventing a jQuery selector.

Comment: yes .. thanks for letting me know ....:)..updated my answer.. please check ..out of my mind.. today..:p

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `list` as ID of the UL – just to avoid problem in case you have multiple UL around the page:

```
$("ul#list")
    .find(".selected").removeClass("selected")
    .end()
    .find("[data-tab-id=" + cat_id + "]").addClass("selected");
```

You can also do that in two jQuery calls, of course:

```
$("ul#list .selected").removeClass("selected");
$("ul#list [data-tab-id=" + cat_id + "]").addClass("selected");
```

Comment: Misses the point where the poster says that the cat_id may be empty. Need an if statement around the code.

Comment: As far as I understand from the question, `cat_id` is empty only at startup, when the default `li` is selected. This code is not executed in this context, but when the user navigate on another tab, therefore `cat_id` is set. If it's not the case, then I need a better context from the OP (e.g. when this code will be executed).

Answer (score 1):

use this sample

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $('ul li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
})
```

Comment: Poster is asking how to select it on page load from a variable. This does not answer that.

Comment: Lets see your answer then please epascarello as i am in need of the same thing :)

Comment: @ConnorMiles: have a look at the question epascarello linked to, above.