# Find jQuery attribute value using jQuery [name='+filename]

Tags: jquery

I'm making dynamic gallery

here is part of my code

```
<li id="pic_0">
 <img src="http://localhost/wpff/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/family/small/012_family-portrait_people_sea.jpg" name="012_family-portrait_people_sea.jpg" horz="y">
</li>
<li id="pic_1">
 <img src="http://localhost/wpff/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/family/small/011_family-portrait_people_sea.jpg" name="011_family-portrait_people_sea.jpg" horz="y">
</li>
<li id="pic_2">
 <img src="http://localhost/wpff/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/family/small/010_family-portrait_mother-son_sea.jpg" name="010_family-portrait_mother-son_sea.jpg" horz="y">
</li>
```

file names generated on the fly. 
I want to get "horz" value knowing filename (name value stored in Bigpic variable) using jquery

```
var horz = $('name='+Bigpic).attr('horz');
```

Cannot get it right!
A little help please.

Thanks.
Alexei

Comment: "on the fly", so they are dynamic, in that case, which "event" are you needing that variable `horz` for?

Comment: Well, you didn't provide a valid selector. Look at the syntax for attributes selectors: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/.

Comment: `attribute selectors` must be encased between `[]`.

Comment: FYI, I don't think the `name` attribute is valid for `img` elements (not to mention `horz`). Consider using `data-*` attributes. If you decide to do this, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2487747/218196.

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is incorrect, Try this way after the element has been created:

```
var horz = $('[name="'+Bigpic + '"]').attr('horz');
```

Also consider changing the attribute name `horz` to `data-horz` and use data api to retrieve the value.

```
var horz = $('[name="'+Bigpic + '"]').data('horz');
```

Also make sure to enclose the attribute value in double quotes, since it has some reserved chars (`.`) and for the standard way of using it.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b29j6/)**

Comment: gj, i was gettin it, but you gots it, fyi, the `"` arn't really needed

Comment: @alexela He means you rewrite your `img` tag builder to include the `attribute` for `data-horz="y"`

Comment: This one i get. But will this may difference? not horz but data-horz?

Comment: @alexela see the fiddle updated.

Comment: `Also make sure to enclose the attribute value in double quotes, since it has some reserved chars and the standard way of using it.` ... where? I really don't see the need for the double quotes, lol

Comment: horz is not a valid html attribute, your html will fail validation. custom attributes needs to be prefixed with data-*

Comment: @SpYk3HH just remove double quotes and see for yourself. `.` is present in the selector.

Comment: I'm not getting the result. undefined variable. 
 `var horz = $('[name="'+Bigpic + '"]').attr('horz');`

Comment: @alexela see the fiddle closely. what is Bigpic by the way.

Comment: PSL - understand. thanks!

Comment: @PSL yea i saw that, lol, that's odd, i've never double quoted my name tags in a selector and never had a problem. First time for everything! First time i've seen that! lol

Comment: @SpYk3HH infact you should always quote the attribute values while using attribute selector, jquery docs itself say that as the standard.

Comment: @PSL I know i know, i've read them ... but i get like a .3 second increase when i dont!  :-P j/k it's just an old habbit. Old habbit of not using double quotes unless absolutely necessary due to the extra parse time in some languages.

Comment: @SpYk3HH yeah... lol... :)

Comment: Yes. I also used `.attr('data-horz')` to setting values since `.data(horz, value)` just nut working (also searched for solution on the web). Selection itself working. So big thanks. My problem was also the place of getting values. I didn't noticed that I'm setting values in function that called after this code (`var horz...`)

Comment: @alexela if you set `.data(horz, value)` then you must access the value as `.data(horz)` not as `.attr('data-horz')` that could be your problem. But if this helped you in anyways do remember to mark as answer and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: if i'm declaring it as .data(horz,value) it not wokring. only as .attr('data-horz',value)