# Testing if JQuery tooltip is initialized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, conditional-statements, jquery-tooltip

I am using a JQuery UI Tooltip along with AJAX to validate a form.

I am using one tooltip for each fields and I am changing the content of this tooltip depending on the error my AJAX return.

For my code to be complete I need to test if the tooltip is already initialize for this field (change content) if not (create the tooltip).

The problem is that I dont know any affective method of checking if the tooltip is initialize or not.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text1"/>
<input type="text" id="text2"/>
```

I have tried the following but they all fail to test if the tooltip is already created or not.

JQUERY:

```
if($("#text1").tooltip() != null) //or $("#text1").tooltip() != 'undefined'
//does'nt work because .tooltip() always return an object.

if(typeof $("#text1").tooltip() != null)//or typeof $("#text1").tooltip() != 'undefined'
//does'nt work always return an object.

if($("#text1").tooltip().hasOwnProperty('option'))//or $("#text1").tooltip().hasOwnProperty('content')
//does'nt work it always return false.
```

If someone could help me find a way to check if the tooltip exist it'd be really appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve, I created a single tooltip that use the title attribute of my html elements. Instead of checking if the tooltip exist to create a new one or update the existing one I update the title attribute of the element.

Answer (score 23):

Just check `data('ui-tooltip')` on your element. See example:

```
if($element.data('ui-tooltip')) {
    $element.tooltip('destroy');
}
```

Comment: Small code-candy $el.filter(":hasData('ui-tooltip')").tooltip("destroy") <- to make this work you will need an pseudo-selector extension method found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41061135/863651

Answer (score 1):

Just an update if anyone is using a newer version, you can simply check for `tooltipstered` class:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("tooltipstered")) {
    // Init
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use the jquery-method is():

```
$('#timelinechecker').is(':ui-tooltip')
```

so you can use:

```
if($('#timelinechecker').is(':ui-tooltip')) {
  // ... do what else...
}
```