# How to find the elements with same data-* attributes and remove the duplicate items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a list of `<tr>` elements in a `<table>` and it has custom data attributes in `<tr>` and `<td>` elements.

This table has some duplicate `<tr>` tags with same data-* attributes.. which I don't want to be displayed in the page.

How can I determine the data-* attribute and get its value and find the duplicate elements on the page in that table, and remove the extra `<tr>` tags.

This is my HTML code after the page is generated:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr class="clickable" data-hiddenfields="{&quot;hiddenFields&quot;:[]}" data-link="/site/product/1" data-index="0">
        <td data-fieldvalue="Username" data-fieldname="Name">
            <div data-fieldname="Username"></div>
            <span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="Username" name="checkbox" class="thumbnail">
            </span> Username
        </td>
        <td data-fieldvalue="Username"data-fieldname="FormLable">
            <div data-fieldname="Username"></div><span></span>Username
        </td>
        <td data-fieldvalue="Username" data-fieldname="FieldName">
            <div data-fieldname="Username"></div><span></span>Username
        </td>
        <td data-fieldvalue="2" data-fieldname="id">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable" data-hiddenfields="{&quot;hiddenFields&quot;:[]}" data-link="/site/product/1" data-index="1">
        <td data-fieldvalue="Username" data-fieldname="Name">
            <div data-fieldname="Username"></div>
            <span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="Username" name="checkbox" class="thumbnail">
            </span> Username
        </td>
        <td data-fieldvalue="Username" data-fieldname="FormLable">
            <div data-fieldname="Username"></div><span></span>Username
        </td>
<td data-fieldvalue="Username" data-fieldname="FieldName">
        <div data-fieldname="Username"></div><span></span>Username
    </td>
    <td data-fieldvalue="2" data-fieldname="id">2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have done removing the elements with `data-link="value"` but the value for data-link is dynamic..so how can i get it..

And how can I remove only the text `Username` in second and third `<td>` if they have an input element inside it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCbp8/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting element by data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Your first question :

```
var searchText = $('tr').first().attr("data-link");
var el = $('tr[data-link="'+searchText+'"]');
console.log(el.length);
el[1].remove();
```

jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/FCbp8/3/