# Find div by data-name attribute

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to find a `<div>` with some specific "`data-name`" attribute value?

For example: I need to find the `<div data-name="place">` to include some code in it dynamically.

Comment: The [jQuery attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), also there are [many more selectors that jQuery supports](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: I think your question is already answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute?rq=1

Answer (score 11):

Sure, use `$('div[data-name="place"]')`