# Change style of object by using condition

Tags: jquery

I have a few html object with the same data-id number (data-id=9)

Is it possible to change the style of these objects by the condition data-id=9 in jquery?

Comment: `$("div").filter("[data-id=9]").addClass("style-class")`

Comment: Sure, use an [Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting element by data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute) and [many others](https://www.google.com/#q=jquery%20select%20by%20attribute%20site:stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1):

try as below, it is a example

HTML

```
<div data-id="9">Hello</div>
<div data-id="9">Hello</div>
<div data-id="9">Hello</div>
<div data-id="10">Hello</div>
```

JS

```
$('div[data-id="9"]').addClass("hi");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fLmbma8v/)

Comment: Yes i tried it. Hello is not getting red for me in Explorer 11