# How to change the innerHtml content using 'data-id' attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<li data-id="528">
  <a title="LOGIN" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>LOGIN</a>
  <div style="width: 350px;" data-width="350" data-class="menu-login-row">My other content</div>
</li>
```

I Have this html I want to change the content by data-id like given below

```
<li data-id="528">
  <a title="LOGOUT" href="/logout">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>LOGOUT</a>
  <div style="width: 350px;" data-width="350" data-class="menu-login-row">My other content</div>
</li>
```

Is this possible if, Please advice me

Thank you.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to accomplish, question is quite vague

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute

Comment: you can get it like `$("li[data-id=528]") `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Like this

```
var a=$('li[data-id="528"]').find('a');
a.attr('href','/logout');
a.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('LOGIN','LOGOUT');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the element by attribute selector, and use .html() to modify content:

```
$('[data-id="528"]').html('<a title="LOGOUT" href="/logout"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>LOGOUT</a><div style="width: 350px;" data-width="350" data-class="menu-login-row">My other content</div>')
```

Actually you can modify innerHtml of an jquery element by .html()

```
$(selector).html(whatEverYouWant);
```

Comment: you can't do this..because it will remove `<a title="LOGIN" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">` also and structure will be `<li data-id="528"><a title="LOGOUT" href="/logout"></a></li>`

Comment: @debin please note that the OP question is How to change the "innerHtml content", not mention about what you are saying, plus, you only need to wrap what you want in .html() is the same.

Comment: He wants to change innerHTML like `<li data-id="528">
  <a title="LOGOUT" href="/logout">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>LOGOUT</a>`

Comment: I think he want to know how to change the content by data-id, so what I mean is op can use .html() to change to anything he wants. But I modify answer as your mention :)

Comment: He specified what he wants in innerHTML in `data-id` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
var htmlData = '<a title="LOGOUT" href="/logout">';
    htmlData+= '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>LOGOUT</a>';
    htmlData+='<div style="width: 350px;" data-width="350" data-class="menu-login-row">My other content</div>';  


jQuery('li[data-id="528"]').html(htmlData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write just one line code for this

```
$('li[data-id="528"]').find('a').attr("title","LOGOUT").attr("href","/logout").html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>LOGOUT</a>');
```