# How to click on a child of LI with data attribute in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want jQuery to do a (simulated) click on a radio button inside an LI with a data attribute named product. Below code is not doing the trick. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var clicky = 1234;
var selector = 'li[data-product="' + clicky + '"].radio';

jQuery(selector).trigger('click');
```

Comment: If it is dynamic element use `delegate` `event` binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting element by data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute)

Comment: What you have should work, assuming the element exists in the DOM. Do you have a specific problem with the code? Seeing your HTML may help us find an issue.

Comment: Your description indicates a hierarchy, but your selector assume the `data-product`, and the `.radio` class are both on the `LI` element. Try using descendant selectors as per example below, and please *please* post your HTML when asking a question like this :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the actual HTML as things can vary slightly based on the DOM, but all your selectors are operating on the same element, not on an element *and its descendants*. Simply adding a space between selectors makes them descendant selectors.

Try something like:

```
var clicky = 1234;
var selector = 'li[data-product="'+clicky+'"] .radio';

jQuery(selector)[0].click();  // Trigger native click event
```

or

```
jQuery(selector).click();  // Trigger jQuery click event
```

Basically you are missing a space before the `.radio`. Currently you are trying to click the LI instead on the descendant.

or possibly

```
var selector = 'li [data-product="'+clicky+'"].radio';
```

if the button has the data (missing space after `LI`).

Comment: I've got things working with  : jQuery(selector).children("input[type=radio]").click();

Comment: Does the same thing as a selector (only longer). Next time provide the HTML too please :)