# How to I exclude selected tr's based on multiple :not()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following

```
$("tr[data-id]:not([data-id='" + id + "'])")
```

that gets all the rows in the table except the one I want to exclude based on id value, but I now need to also exclude those where the checkbox is disabled, but I cant figure out how to incorporate the additional parameter into the selector statement.

Below is an example of a row that should be excluded ..... based on its checkbox disabled attr

```
<tr data-id="5">            
    <td>
        <label style="position:relative">
            <input class="active status-color checkbox-slider yesno " title="no" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
            <span class="text"></span>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks.

I need rows that DO NOT match the id variable AND of those rows DO NOT contain a checkbox that IS disabled

Comment: Current CSS implementations afaik do not support a parent selector. So you wont be able to select the row directly by its content. you will have to select the checkbox first and the use some thing like `closest( 'tr' )` to get the table row.

Comment: Maybe you help this answer: [Selecting element by data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487751/5925490)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made me crazy... 
**https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/em1cjuas/**

```
$("tr[data-id!="+id+"]:not(:has('input[type=checkbox]:disabled'))")
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear ... I'm looking to select all the rows; except ones with a matching ID; and ones that contain a disalbed checkbox

Comment: ok but what if the element with the matching ID has a disalbed checkbox? Include or not in the selector?

Comment: can you please check it https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/615xjrqy I'm getting lost in your explanation...

Comment: Element with the matching ID will never be disabled.

All that I need is rows that DO NOT match the id variable AND of those matching rows DO NOT contain a checkbox that IS disabled

Comment: So you are looking to select all the rows, except ones with a matching ID, and  except the ones that contain a disalbed checkbox???

Answer (score 1):

Use `has` & `:enabled` like following.

```
$('tr[data-id]:not([data-id="' + id + '"]):has(":checkbox:enabled")')
```

Or you can use `filter` like following.

```
$('tr[data-id]:not([data-id="' + id + '"])').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find(':checkbox:disabled').length == 0;
});
```