# Locating a data-attribute via jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

can anyone assist in locating the anchor tag via jQuery which contains a matching data-attribute please and then applying a class to it

e.g. code

```
<a href="#" data-label="test1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" data-label="test2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" data-label="test3">Link 3</a>
```

So if I pass a function the value "test2" a class of highlight would be applied to that one?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Comment: Or [Selecting element by data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the element based on the attribute value.

```js
$('[data-label="test2"]').addClass('active')
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-label="test1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" data-label="test2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" data-label="test3">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: Wow thanks for fast reply - completely didnt think of using that method Id been testing with find() - great I will mark this as accepted shortly

Comment: var setActiveLabel = function(data) { $('[data-label="'+data+'"]').addClass('active')};

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" data-label="test1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" data-label="test2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" data-label="test3">Link 3</a>

addclass('test2');
function addclass(x){
$('[data-label="'+  x +'"]').addClass('active');
}

.active{
  color: red;
}
```