# select a div with a certain data attribute without each loop

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='bwrap' data-x='home01'></div>
<div class='bwrap hidden' data-x='home02'></div>
<div class='bwrap hidden' data-x='home03'></div>
<div class='bwrap hidden' data-x='home04'></div>
```

I want to show `.bwrap` with `data-x='home04'` without `each` loop.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute) I tried:

**js**

```
var obj = $('.bwrap[data-x="home04"]');
obj.show();
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: did you rounded it up in  doucment ready?

Comment: @JurijJazdanov, it's a `click` event.

Comment: How are you hiding the element and are you running that jQuery on document ready because your code works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/eyack83r/

Comment: show all relevant code in OP

Comment: also show() won't remove hidden class. show()/hide() changes display style of the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked fine if:-

1.jQuery library added before your script code.

2.code is wrapped inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

3.Since div have no text that's why you may confuse that it's not shown. Add some text to that div and check.

Working example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var obj = $('.bwrap[data-x="home04"]');
  obj.show();
  //can change in one-liner like :- $('.bwrap[data-x="home04"]').show();
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery library needed-->
<div class='bwrap' data-x='home01'>01</div><!-- added text to show that your code worked-->
<div class='bwrap hidden' data-x='home02'>02</div><!-- added text to show that your code worked-->
<div class='bwrap hidden' data-x='home03'>03</div><!-- added text to show that your code worked-->
<div class='bwrap hidden' data-x='home04'>04</div><!-- added text to show that your code worked-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show (means remove `hidden` class)

You can do just following

```
$('.bwrap[data-x="home04"]').show();
```