# jquery data tag not returning values

Tags: attr

My page contains a table of elements.  Each row has a data tag (identified as "reckey" because that's how the database was set up years before I came on the scene).  Stepping through my javascript as it builds the table, I can see that the tags are being set correctly.  I.e., this line:

```
$("#tblActivities tbody tr:first").data("reckey")
```

returns a value of '122157'.  But when I try to search for that row by way of this line:

```
$("#tblActivities tbody tr[data-reckey='122157']")
```

my browser indicates it's undefined.  I've also tried it as

```
$("#tblActivities tbody tr[attr-data-reckey='122157']")
```

and just for s's & g's, I tried

```
$("#tblActivities tbody tr[data-reckey]"), which still returned undefined.
```

Can someone please show me what I'm missing?  I wouldn't be at all surprised if it's a simple syntax error, although I hope it's something deeper if only so I don't feel like quite as complete an idiot.

Thanks,

Comment: is the data added via javascript or plain html `data-reckey=122157` ? also, what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11673313/123422, possibly?

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai, I'm adding the data tag via javascript, but could change that to include it in the string that builds the HTML instead.  As for the version, I'm using 2.2.0.

Comment: @PaulAbbott Your link is likely to be the problem.  Thank you for that link.  Although the fix recommended in one of the comments on that question doesn't appear to solve my problem, it at least points me in the right direction, which is to include the data tag at the time the html is built instead of changing it after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding the data attribute with Javascript, you won't be able to select it directly (i.e. via the  `$('[data-reckey="122157"]')`, as it jQuery stores the data inside the jQuery object, not the html.

So, if you can, either place the `data-reckey=""` directly into HTML, or iterate through elements, for example like this:

```
$("#tblActivities tbody tr").each(function () {
    if ( $(this).data('reckey') === '122157' ) {
        // found the element...
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For confirmation in case someone else searches for this same problem later: the solution was to include the data tag at the time the html is created instead of changing it via jquery later.