# Style Tag Data attributes with javascript or jq

Tags: javascript, jquery

its possible style the attribute data? for example i have this code

```
<div data-visual-id="1">
bla bla bla
</div>
```

and i have only this code for add a style **"display:none"**
obviously the div can not hide it otherwise hide other parts of the site

Comment: why not just give it a class ??

Comment: there is the class but not work <div class="ytp-title" data-visual-id="1">

Comment: class should work, how have you tried with class ?

Comment: the very problem is ..this http://prntscr.com/gygpr7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simly this way:

```
$('*[data-visual-id="1"]').css({'display': 'none'});
```

For more information, go to this link [Selecting element by data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute).

Comment: javascript its possible?

Comment: have you seen the link I provided? in one of the answers there someone provided example in javascript

Comment: anyway, `document.querySelectorAll('[data-visual-id="1"]')[0].style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **attribute-selector** to get it done. Check this [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/) for more reference. Check below snippet.

```css
div[data-visual-id="1"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-visual-id="1">
  bla bla bla
</div>
```

Comment: and javascript ?

Comment: Why do you need javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Ah but of course it's possible, your CSS selector would look something like this

```css
div[data-visual-id="1"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div data-visual-id="1">
  bla bla bla
</div>
```