# Select a tag with custom data value and change its href with jquery

Tags: jquery, href, selector

I have this piece of codes:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" data-ga-label="666666666" target="_blank"></a>
```

I want to select this ***a*** tag with jquery based-on ***"data-ga-label"*** attribute that have a ***666666666*** value and change its href.
How it's possible with jquery?
Thank you.

Comment: You can use the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2487747/4202224) question coping with your problem

Comment: `$("#setAnId").attr("href", "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + $(this).attr('data-ga-label'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add selectors for custom data like below, and then change the `href` attribute of the link.

```js
$('a[data-ga-label="666666666"]').attr('href', 'https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" data-ga-label="666666666" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can use the [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the element. You can then use the `attr` function to change the `href` location.

You can also do this in one line, as @Henkan does in his answer. I just split it up to explain what each step does.

Example:

```js
// This selects the element using the attribute equals selector
let el = $("a[data-ga-label='666666666']");

// This modifies the href using the attr function
$(el).attr("href", "google.com");

// Show updated link
console.log($(el).attr("href"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" data-ga-label="666666666" target="_blank"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a[data-ga-label="666666666"]').attr('href', 'https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" data-ga-label="666666666" target="_blank">Link</a>
```