# jQuery - Match elements with same data

Tags: jquery

I like to match textarea data with span data when you type in each textarea to retun char left in the span with same data

How to match them ?

**html**

```
 <span data-lang="gb"></span>
<textarea data-lang="gb"></textarea>

<span data-lang="en"></span>
<textarea data-lang="en"></textarea>
```

**jquery**

```
 $('textarea').each(function(){
  var lang = $(this).data('lang');
  $(this).keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.length > 50) {
      return false;
    }
    $('span').html("(characters left: " +(50 - $(this).val().length) + " )");
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok?  What have you tried?  I don't see any selector in this snippet trying to get the span.

Comment: You want it so when you type in a textarea, a span with the same `data-lang` shows the textarea char count?

Comment: yes exactly that i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to the point:

```
$('textarea').each(function(){
  var lang = $(this).data('lang');
  $(this).keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.length > 50) {
      return false;
    }
    $('span[data-lang="'+lang+'"]').html("(characters left: " +(50 - $(this).val().length) + " )");
  });
});
```

As you can see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute) you can select an element by data attribute. 
Please note that this code is untested

Comment: that i was looking for 'span[data-lang="'+lang+'"]' 
thanks a lot you are master :)

Comment: Thank you. If this is what you are looking for please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make a data attribute in your text area telling it what is it's counter element and use it to select and update the counter.

Like this:

```js
$("[data-counter]").on('input', function (e) {
  var counter = $(this).data('counter');
  var $counter = $(counter);
  var maxlength = parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'));
  var count = $(this).val().length;
  $counter.text('Characters left: ' + (maxlength - count));
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="mytext" data-counter="#mytextcounter" maxlength="50"></textarea>
<span id="mytextcounter"></span>
```