# How to use the method : $().button('toggle') for this bootstrap 'radio-button list'?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" 
        checked> Active
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> 
        Radio
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 
        Radio
    </label>
</div>
```

$().button('toggle') : Toggles push state. Gives the button the appearance that it has been activated.

Screenshot of image of RadioButtonList. From the left-most button you can see that it looks like it has been clicked when it is clicked.

[image]

Screenshot of the Login-page that I am currently making. When I click on either of the 'radio' buttons their appearance does not changed, so I have to use the method $().button('toggle'), but I do not know where or how to use it.

[image]

Comment: what are u trying to achieve with ur code?, do you want the have a javascript/jquery code to toggle the `clicked` state?

Comment: Yes @RamondeVries. I do not know where to put or how to use the method $().button('toggle').

Comment: did you litterly use `$().button('toggle') ` or something like this `$('.btn-group').button('toggle') `?

Comment: Yeah already did actually @RamondeVries

Comment: Sorry guys real dumb but I did not put the JavaScript and JQuery script src properly into my HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the correct selector to the jQuery function. Try using this instead:

```
$(".btn-group").button("toggle");
```

And now your code should work.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question because I was stumped by a similar use case. It's my first time working with jquery, so I was a little confused by the syntax at first.  (tl;dr diff between JS/jquery see 4.)

I wanted to expand on the 1st answer because I would have appreciated someone else doing the same.  I was working through this problem on Bootstrap 4.5.3 for a couple hours, completely stumped as to why my radio buttons wouldn't show the toggle effect, before I realized there was a library requirement for the `button()` method, which I did not see in the docs.

1. **The required library:** If you want this feature to work "the bootstrap way", the `buttons.js` library before invoking the jquery script, which in an npm-installed package is located at `node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/`

Load + init example:

```
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/buttons.js">
    $('.btn-group').button('toggle');
    </script>
```

you can disaggregate the jquery and loading the script if that helps you keep things straight (separate `<script />` tags for each):

```
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/buttons.js"> </script>
    <script>$('.btn-group').button('toggle');</script>
```

2. **Selecting the proper element for your use case:** A slightly more specific way to target the buttons is explained by TWBS in another bootstrap example for tooltips - this is targeting the children of an element by data attribute:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere

```
    $('[data-toggle="button"]').button('toggle');
```

More about selecting element by data attribute here: [Selecting element by data attribute with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute-with-jquery)

3. **Right target for use case continued:** You can attach it to elements in any number of ways, here's an example using the IDs of each button, the `#` hash symbol denoting an ID selector (the `.` period symbol denoting a class, just like `css`) - you simply put them in an array and pass that to the `button()` method:

```
    $(['#option1', '#option2', '#option3']).button('toggle');
```

This could be classes (starting with a period, e.g. `['.button-one', '.button-two']`, etc.

4. **Big picture:** If you're seeing the pattern here, jquery uses these
   `$(DOM ELEMENT).method(SCOPE)` statements, which are a more terse form of the syntax used by JS, which would be a lot more verbose, something like:

```
    let lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    let firstLi = lis[0];
    firstLi.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked first li'))
```

So it's basically the same, just way less verbose. Since jquery was developed specifically to handle the DOM, this makes sense.

If you want to achieve the same *look* without loading the bootstrap `buttons.js` library, you can attach/remove the `.active` class, which when attached mutes the appearance of the radio button, to the label of the buttons in question with something like:

```
    $('.btn').on('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings('label').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
```

**Statement exmplained:** When an element with the `.btn` class is clicked, it will remove all `.active` classes from any sibling elements with the tag type `label`, and add the `.active` class to the one you clicked.

If you examine the `button.js` library, though, you can see that `toggle()` does quite a bit more stuff behind the scenes than just applying/removing `.active` (and has many, many, many conditionals for different possible use cases...):

```
     _proto.toggle = function toggle() {
          var triggerChangeEvent = true;
          var addAriaPressed = true;
          var rootElement = $__default['default'](this._element).closest(SELECTOR_DATA_TOGGLES)[0];
    
          if (rootElement) {
            var input = this._element.querySelector(SELECTOR_INPUT);
    
            if (input) {
              if (input.type === 'radio') {
                if (input.checked && this._element.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME_ACTIVE)) {
                  triggerChangeEvent = false;
                } else {
                  var activeElement = rootElement.querySelector(SELECTOR_ACTIVE);
    
                  if (activeElement) {
                    $__default['default'](activeElement).removeClass(CLASS_NAME_ACTIVE);
                  }
                }
              }
    
              if (triggerChangeEvent) {
                // if it's not a radio button or checkbox don't add a pointless/invalid checked property to the input
                if (input.type === 'checkbox' || input.type === 'radio') {
                  input.checked = !this._element.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME_ACTIVE);
                }
    
                if (!this.shouldAvoidTriggerChange) {
                  $__default['default'](input).trigger('change');
                }
              }
    
              input.focus();
              addAriaPressed = false;
            }
          }
    
          if (!(this._element.hasAttribute('disabled') || this._element.classList.contains('disabled'))) {
            if (addAriaPressed) {
              this._element.setAttribute('aria-pressed', !this._element.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME_ACTIVE));
            }
    
            if (triggerChangeEvent) {
              $__default['default'](this._element).toggleClass(CLASS_NAME_ACTIVE);
            }
          }
        };
```

So, probably best just to load `button.js`...

Side Note: Arrow functions in jquery more often than not wind up targeting the `window` object, so might be best to avoid unless you know what you're doing.