# find() pseudo element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

html:

```
<div id="pai_pergunta_0" class="col s12 card-panel hoverable box-pai" data-id="0" data-tipo="TEXT">
</div>

<div id="pai_pergunta_1" class="col s12 card-panel hoverable box-pai" data-id="1" data-tipo="RADIO">
</div>

<div id="pai_pergunta_2" class="col s12 card-panel hoverable box-pai" data-id="1" data-tipo="CHECKBOX">
</div>
```

My form it's dynamic, and i need to remove one div after each data-tipo="TEXT".
If I want to find the class "box-pai" i just find('.box-pai'), but how can I find the pseudo element **data-tipo="TEXT"** ?

Comment: Did you search in google or stackoverflow before posting?
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute

Comment: Side note: "pseudo-element" has [a specific meaning](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#gen-content) in web programming, and there aren't any in your question. (A *pseudo-element* is the fake element created by providing text in a `::before` or `::after` rule in CSS.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select by attribute, and then use `.next("div")` to find the next div...

```js
$("[data-tipo=TEXT]").next("div").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pai_pergunta_0" class="col s12 card-panel hoverable box-pai" data-id="0" data-tipo="TEXT">
TEXT
</div>

<div id="pai_pergunta_1" class="col s12 card-panel hoverable box-pai" data-id="1" data-tipo="RADIO">
RADIO
</div>

<div id="pai_pergunta_2" class="col s12 card-panel hoverable box-pai" data-id="1" data-tipo="CHECKBOX">
CHECKBOX
</div>
```